# How do I access PHPMyAdmin after install in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, phpmyadmin, localhost

I installed Apache and then PHPMyAdmin on my Ubuntu server, but I have not been able to access PHPMyAdmin at `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`. `http://localhost` is working however.

Comment: Where did you install phpmyadmin to?

Comment: How did you "install" it? It should just be in whatever folder you put it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What errors did the error logs (access and or error logs)? That would help determining the issue. Could be a socket issue, but could be a url issue too. I assume PHP is installed too?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps
http://tech2view.com/not-able-to-access-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-404-not-found-error/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an Ubuntu server with initial setup and a LAMP Server

If you haven't installed the LAMP Server. You can follow the steps on the below link to install it.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Then Install the phpMyAdmin in your server. Follow the steps on the link below.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Did you install MySQL?

Another possibility is to download phpmyadmin and extract is to htdocs/phpmyadmin.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` and getting 404 Error then follow steps.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the phpmyadmin config to the file:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

then restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```